# How to filter table with RegEx in VBA?

Tags: excel, regex, vba, filter

I have a table with column of IP Address, some of them have a mask with  CIDR notation (1.1.1.1/16 for example).

I would like to filter that table with a regex expression, I tried it in Regex101 and it is what I need :

`"[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}\/(($[0-9]|[0-9] )|(1[0-9]))"`

How can I apply the filter to my table with my regex, only show lines where regex is true ?

Comment: Implement the regex as a UDF. Add a column to your table for testing and filter on `True` (or use it as a formula criteria for the Advanced Filter)

Comment: Thank you, it was very easy but I didn't think to create a new column, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

First check this is in Tools -> references  :

[image]

Then you should follow this example :

```
        Dim current_string As String
        Dim my_pattern As String
        my_pattern = "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}\/(($[0-9]|[0-9] )|(1[0-9]))"
        Dim my_regexp As RegExp
        With my_regexp
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = my_pattern 
        End With
        For i = 1 To N
            current_string = Range("A" & i).Text
            If my_regexp.test(current_string)=False Then
                Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True ' we only hide rows that doesn't match the regexp.
            End If
        Next i
```

Let me know if it helps !

Comment: It looks like it's working, thank you !
Here is the final code after few modifications :

Comment: ```Sub filter()
    Dim current_string As String
    Set my_regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    my_regexp.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}\/(($[0-9]|[0-9] )|(1[0-9]))"
    my_regexp.Global = False
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        current_string = Cells(i, "I")
        If my_regexp.test(current_string) = False Then
            Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True ' we only hide rows that doesn't match the regexp.
        End If
    Next i
End Sub```